# what is the meaning of "bag the job"

Tags: what-that

What is the meaning of **bag the job**? I saw this expression in this sentence:`Job-hunting: How to bag that first job`. I have looked up it in the dictionary but no meaning goes with the sentence. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: *to bag* = to get. "claim something **4** *bag something* (British English, informal) to claim something as yours before somebody else claims it; to take something before somebody else can get it *Sally had managed to bag the two best seats.* OALD http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bag_2

Comment: Please also visit [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: I thought this was originally "It's in the bag" meaning that the object (person/place/thing) was already acquired.  From there, it was changed into the verb "to bag", meaning you're getting it into the bag or acquiring it.  Pure speculation, though.

Answer (score 2):

I have always thought of that use of *bag* to derive from a hunting analogy.

> *Are you hunting for a new job?*
>
> *No. I just bagged a great one yesterday!*

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bag&searchmode=none), in discussing *bag*, gives a hint of that possible derivation

> Many figurative senses, such as the verb meaning "to kill game" (1814) and its colloquial extension to "catch, seize, steal" (1818) are from the notion of the game bag (late 15c.) into which the product of the hunt was placed.

Answer (score 0):

"Bag" can be used [as a verb](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bag), meaning:

> 2.1Succeed in securing (something): 
> ‘we’ve bagged three awards for excellence’
>   
> ‘get there early to bag a seat in the front row’

So, in this context, it means "to secure your first job".

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the meaning of the phrase, try splitting it into parts and look them up in the dictionary. In this case we would want to look up "bag". Quick search, first dictionary ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bag)), and we choose the right definition:

> to get (something desired)